# Missing return statement, what i am missing

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I written a method which will acknowledge the controller by returning true and false, I return true inside try if everything goes fine it will return true and I return false inside catch blocks, but still method shows me error `"missing return statement"` what is the best way to do it.

The below method written in java will send back the true or false to the controller.

Secondly I want to carry the exception message from here to controller, I think of returning string, is it good approach,

Kindly suggest me the best way to do the exception handling

```
 public boolean pickSalayData(String yearMonth, String regionId, String circleId, Userdetail loginUser) throws MyExceptionHandler {
        String tableSuffix = yearMonth.substring(4, 6) + yearMonth.substring(0, 4);

        log.info("Pick Salary Data From ERP " + DateUtility.dateToStringDDMMMYYYY(new Date()));
        List<SalaryDetailReport> detailReports = hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO.findAll(yearMonth, regionId, circleId);

        TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus trstatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
        try {
            List<SalaryDetailReport> salaryDetailReport = null;
            int countDetail = 0;
            if (detailReports != null && detailReports.size() > 0) {

                for (SalaryDetailReport salary : detailReports) {
                    try {
                        if (countDetail % COMMIT_COUNT == 0) {
                            if (salaryDetailReport != null) {
                                salaryDetailReportDAO.save(salaryDetailReport, tableSuffix);
                                reportHistoryDAO.save(salaryDetailReport, loginUser);
                            }
                            salaryDetailReport = new ArrayList<SalaryDetailReport>();
                        }
                        salaryDetailReport.add(salary);
                        countDetail++;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error on Save Salary Pay Head Details Data from ERP to Prayas .");
                    }
                }
                if (salaryDetailReport != null && salaryDetailReport.size() > 0) {
                    salaryDetailReportDAO.save(salaryDetailReport, tableSuffix);
                    reportHistoryDAO.save(salaryDetailReport, loginUser);
                }
            } else {
                throw new MyExceptionHandler("No record for Save in Database from ERP.");
            }
            salaryDetailReportDAO.update(tableSuffix, regionId, circleId);
            List<SalaryDetailReport> reports = salaryDetailReportDAO.findAll(tableSuffix, regionId, circleId);
            if (reports != null && reports.size() > 0) {
                for (SalaryDetailReport salaryDetail : reports) {
                    try {
                        SalaryDetail sd = new SalaryDetail();
                        sd.setDetailReport(salaryDetail);
                        salaryDetailDAO.save(sd, tableSuffix);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("Error occured", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new MyExceptionHandler(" Error :" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("data found");

            } else {
                log.error("Salary Record Not Found.");
                throw new MyExceptionHandler("No record Found.");
            }
            salaryDetailDAO.updateEarningDeduction(tableSuffix);
            //salaryDetailDAO.updateEarningDeductionsInSDT();
            transactionManager.commit(trstatus);
            try {
                hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO.update(regionId, circleId, yearMonth);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Some error : ", ex);
            }

//            //   System.out.println("Completed =============================");
        } catch (MyExceptionHandler ex) {
            transactionManager.rollback(trstatus);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Failed to Save Salary data  :" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            transactionManager.rollback(trstatus);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Error occured on Save Salary data.", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You miss a `return` statement at the end of your method

Comment: You as a programmer may think that you have all bases covered, but the compiler can not make the same assumptions as yourself, so every `path` needs too have a return at the end

Comment: BTW, remove `e.printStacktrace` and `System.out.println` if you use a logging Framework

Comment: But that's the question why, When my try is already cover the entire code, each time try execute or the catch will executed , so i handle the return there, then why i need to return at last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `return` statement for the following `catch` block :

```
 catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Some error : ", ex);
 }
```

Either you add `return` statement in this `catch` block or at the end of mehtod

Comment: Thank you so much, I also need to track which catch block catches the exception, how can I implement that?

Comment: you saw multiple catch blocks inside the method, say catch 1, catch 2, catch 3, I need to customise the error message, in order to do so, I need to figure it out which catch block catches the exception

Comment: That entirely depends on your code flow ..moreover you need to study exception navigation

Comment: I think to return string concatenated with exception message

Comment: In that case change your return type to String

Comment: yeah definately

Answer (score 0):

If this code throws an Exception, then the following `catch` code will not be entered into and hence there is no return value

```
  try {
     hRMSPickSalaryDataDAO.update(regionId, circleId, yearMonth);
     return true;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     log.error("Some error : ", ex);
     **edit**
     return `true||false`;
  }

} catch (...) {
     return something;
}
```

Comment: How do I fix it then?

Comment: either return `true` or `false` based upon your logic, although throwing exceptions to control flow is not a good idea